# How to write HTML for embedding Flash content

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I am having a URL of some MSN video as http://video.in.msn.com/watch/video/the-help-theatrical-trailer/fcvrtnl7,

I would like to create a HTML document in such a fashion so that if I load that HTML document  then, only that running flash content present in the link mentioned below should come. I have created a HTML doc but when I load that, I am able to see only Flash player on my page , it is not playing any video content in that.

Below mentioned is the HTML code. Please advice am I missing execution of any Javascript, if yes then how to identify which is the required Javascript to get the video loaded in the flash player.

```
<html>
<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0">
<embed 
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    src="http://img.widgets.video.s-msn.com/v/5407.02/fl/player/current/player.swf"     
    width="800" height="450"  "autoplay=false"  
    type="application/x-shockwave-flash"  
    id="rich_embed_460916691"  
    data="http://img.widgets.video.s-msn.com/v/5407.02/fl/player/current/player.swf"  
    PARAM=""  
    bgcolor="#000000"  
    allowScriptAccess="always"  
    quality="high"  
    wmode="window"  
    allowFullScreen="true"
    flashvars="playlistmin=11&ps=10&mode=destination&ifs=true&playAdBeforeFirstVid=true&endslateTime=1&slateAd=true&pl=false&adaptiveBuffering=false&hideShare=false&hideInfo=true&hideSearch=true&hideMoreVideos=true&hidePlaylist=true&rst=v5&mkt=en-in&fr=dest_en-in&reportingType=dest&brand=v5%5e800x450&adEventTimeout=15&adFull=Web&adPartial=Partial&adModelType=MSN&adDivs=ux1_2_1_300x60ad_msn%2c300%2c60%3bplayer1000x650ad%2c1000%2c650%3bplayer1380x1024ad_temp%2c1380%2c1024%3bplayer1380x650ad%2c1380%2c650&timePlaying=60&videosPlayed=1&ad=true&vc=catalog.video.msn.com&vce=edge1.catalog.video.msn.com%2cedge2.catalog.video.msn.com%2cedge3.catalog.video.msn.com%2cedge4.catalog.video.msn.com&vci=img1.catalog.video.msn.com%2cimg2.catalog.video.msn.com%2cimg3.catalog.video.msn.com%2cimg4.catalog.video.msn.com&msnlink=true&linkOverride2=http%3a%2f%2fvideo.in.msn.com%2f%3fmkt%3den-in%26vid%3d%7b0%7d%26from%3d&linkBack=http%3a%2f%2fvideo.in.msn.com%2f&ap=true&widgetId=ux1_2_1_1_5&rv=true&rvp=false&versionPath=%2fv%2f5407.02%2f&qualityOverride=LO"
    />
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

On the page you refer to there is a 'Share' button.
If you click it, it gives you the code you can copy and paste:

```
<iframe 
    width="432" 
    height="243" 
    frameborder="0" 
    marginwidth="0" 
    marginheight='0' 
    scrolling="no" 
    src="http://hub.video.msn.com/embed/b7dad6f8-9355-4ccc-8b1b-d6eea6f28764/?vars=bWt0PWVuLWluJmJyYW5kPXY1JTVlODAweDQ1MCZsaW5rb3ZlcnJpZGUyPWh0dHAlM2ElMmYlMmZ2aWRlby5pbi5tc24uY29tJTJmJTNmbWt0JTNkZW4taW4lMjZ2aWQlM2QlN2IwJTdkJTI2ZnJvbSUzZCZsaW5rYmFjaz1odHRwJTNhJTJmJTJmdmlkZW8uaW4ubXNuLmNvbSUyZiZjb25maWdDc2lkPU1TTlZpZGVvJmNvbmZpZ05hbWU9c3luZGljYXRpb25wbGF5ZXImc3luZGljYXRpb249dGFnJnBsYXllci5mcj1zaGFyZWVtYmVkLXN5bmRpY2F0aW9u">
  <A href="http://video.in.msn.com/?mkt=en-in&vid=b7dad6f8-9355-4ccc-8b1b-d6eea6f28764&from=shareembed-syndication&src=v5:embed:syndication:" target="_new" title="The Help: Theatrical trailer">Video: The Help: Theatrical trailer</A>
</iframe>
```

As @GabrielTheron suggested it is an iframe.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but how do I know that this link is going to open a flash content, because I am only interested to form a HTML doc only for flash contents.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no expert here, but perhaps an iframe might be easier/better to use?
I know it's quite a common way to use external content in a webpage (especially Flash content).